# what is the proper way to deploy microservices written with ASP.Net core web application to production

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, microservices

i have 3 projects for my microservices :

- Api ( api gateway )
- Identitiy ( microservice )
- Activities ( microservice )

Identity service and activity service are both subscribed to few messages using rabbitMQ.

I don't know proper way to deploy them on window server.

should i use

IIS, nix services.dll, Windows Services, dotnet cli

if i run them on IIS, are they always subscribed to messages ( does it keep application running to handle subscriptions?).
is dotnet service.dll ok for production or do i need something like iis or nginx.

Comment: If its asp.net core why are you using windows ? Linux is the way to go. There are different options. For micro-services you would need kubernetes

Comment: @ImranArshad i am trying to migrate my system little by little and for linux it's impossible for now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIS is good enough for you case.

You can configure the IIS  to run your service soon as you deploy it, and it will continue to listen to your RabbitMQ.

Although if you have a service that communicates with other Services using only RabbitMQ I would rather build it as WindowsService.

Hope this helps